# Supervisor is not collect logs from application when WARN loglevel enabled

Tags: docker, docker-compose, supervisord

I have LEMP composite docker container, compiled by **docker-compose**.

I need redirect all WARNING logs from my PHP-application to STDOUT stream of container;
It works only when option of supervisord  **loglevel=debug**:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel=debug
```

And then, logs from PHP applications broadcasts to STDOUT:

> lemp_1   |  lemp_1   | 2017-07-11 19:09:29,524 DEBG 'php-fpm' stdout
>   output: lemp_1   | [11-Jul-2017 19:09:29] WARNING: [pool www] child 13
>   said into stdout: "[2017-07-11 19:09:29] app.NOTICE: hello world [] []"

If i set parameter into supervisord section [supervisord]

```
loglevel=warn
```

(or info,error,alert, etc..) i have no logs in my stdout stream at all!
I need pass to activity log only messages, have WARN level and highter.
How **supervisord** "understands", what level of log message it received from application?
May be it have any specification for log message format?
Or there are not enough settings?

Supervisor configuration:

```
[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm -F
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=5
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
redirect_stderr=true

[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g 'daemon off;'
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=10
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
redirect_stderr=true

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel=debug
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell supervisor to write the stdout of the container to its own supervisord's logs, with:

```
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

So your config is:

```
[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm -F
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=5
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
redirect_stderr=true

[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g 'daemon off;'
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=10
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
redirect_stderr=true

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel=debug
```